# Wit.ai not executing function on detecting entity

Tags: wit.ai

I am trying to make a bot through wit.ai. It is detecting the entity, but it is not calling the function which should be executed on detecting that entity.

For example, if you go to the link here on Witty Fiddle :   https://wit-ai.github.io/witty-fiddle/?id=2a2aafd3e2656e7e74949331b85a6667

And say, `hi`. Bot detects its entity `greeting` and executes function `replyToHi()`. Then if user says `Thank you`, it will detect its entity as `thankyou`  but instead of executing `replyToThankyou()`, it will just display `Hi, how are you`, without executing any function.

Whereas, when I call `Tell me about good comedy movies`, and it discovers intent as `search_query` and calls "findMovieBasedOnSearchItems()". And after that if I say `thankyou`, then it executes `replyToThankyou()` function.

What I am observing is that if it detects the another `entity` after the first one, it does not call `bot executes` functions, whereas after it detects some `intent` and then some `entity`, then it calls bot execute functions.

Please let me is there some bug in `wit.ai` or am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Only trait entities influence function prediction. Instead of using keyword/free-text entities in your stories you should rather set them as trait entity. Also you can set some restrictions in Actions tab to prevent undesirable function callings.

Comment: So for this case, how can we use "trait" for "Greetings", "Thank you" and "Bye"? And also sometimes there execution function is called and other times it is not called.

Comment: You have to remove keywor/free-text entities you set them. And then add entity say intent:greeting. If you add entity without selecting your message it will be automatically set as trait entity. In order to achieve better function prediction you will have to train it more with different type of phrases, sentence structures and etc. Also as I said use Actions tab to prevent wrong action calls.